resp.Result = 'resp.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
resp returns as null, the code stops here when I log in as a user.
program.cs

using Foody.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login";
});

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

// CORS'u ekleyin ve herhangi bir origin'e izin verin
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

// Swagger'ı ekleyin
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

//// Diğer servisleri ekleyin
//builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

// CORS'u kullan
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpointDataSource =>
{
    // Controller route'larını haritalayın
    endpointDataSource.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");  //Login-> Home
});

//// Razor Pages route'larını haritalayın
//app.MapRazorPages();

// API controller'larını haritalayın
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();



LoginController.cs => Foody/Controller
using Foody.Helpers;
using Foody.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;

namespace Foody.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        // HttpClient'i dependency injection ile alıyoruz
        public LoginController(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        // Kullanıcı formunu doldurduktan sonra POST isteği ile API'ye gönderir
        [HttpPost("Login/LoginIndex")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginIndex(UserLoginModel model) // Form verilerini bu eyleme gönderiyoruz
        {
            // ModelState geçerli değilse, formu tekrar gösterir ve kullanıcıya hataları bildirir
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model); // Geçerli değilse, aynı formu tekrar döndürür
            }
            try
            {
                // API'ye GET isteği gönderir ve tüm kategorileri alır
                var resp = ServiceManager.MakeRequest(HttpRequestType.POST, "Login/LoginIndex", model);

                // İstek başarılı olduysa ana sayfaya yönlendiriyoruz
                if (resp.Result)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // Başarıyla giriş yaptıktan sonra yönlendirme
                }
                else
                {
                    // API'den hata dönerse kullanıcıya hata mesajı gösteriyoruz
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Giriş yapılamadı: {resp.ErrorMessage}");
                    return View(model);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // İstek sırasında bir hata oluşursa, kullanıcıya genel bir hata mesajı gösteriyoruz
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Bir hata oluştu: {ex.Message}");
                return View(model);
            }
        }
    }
}



LoginController => FoodyService/Controller
 using FoodyService.DTO.Models;
using FoodyService.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace FoodyService.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly FoodyDbContext _context;

        public LoginController(FoodyDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginIndex(UserLoginModel model)
        {
            // Kullanıcıyı e-posta adresi ve şifresine göre bul
            var user = await _context.Users
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Email == model.Username && u.Password == model.Password);

            // Eğer kullanıcı bulunamazsa hata döndür
            if (user == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { success = false, message = "Geçersiz kullanıcı adı veya şifre" });
            }

            // Giriş başarılı, başarılı yanıt döndür
            return Ok(new { success = true, message = "Giriş başarılı", user});
        }

    }
}


Can you help me solve this problem? After creating a user registration, I want to redirect to Home/index when logged in.
When I go to the home index, I encounter this error in the console.
resp.Result = 'resp.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0  As is you've set a default route of Login controller and Index action.  Your code has no Index action.  Are you using razor pages or just controllers?  You've also set razor endpoints with MapRazorPages.  The routing could be the issue, but it could also be server related.

if not using razorpages, remove builder.Services.AddRazorPages(); and app.MapRazorPages(); in program.cs.

you may want to start with a new basic project type first and get a feel for the routing styles of each.   If you are going with controllers that return views, RazorPages are a pretty good way to go.  Routing is handled via verb of GET or POST.  I would give that type of project a go first.  Run through the basic tutorial and then modify the solution to meet your needs.


I am designing a login panel for my foody project. But when I run the
project, I get:
"This localhost page cannot be found. No web page found for the
following web address: http://localhost:5229/ HTTP ERROR 404".
My port number is correct. I have made the necessary forwarding, why
can't I view the page?

Well, the error you are getting is pretty obvious because of your app.MapControllerRoute definition. If you look at your route configuration, you would seen your MapControllerRoute has {controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}, but your LoginController has the action method named Login, not Index. Change the action method in the route configuration to Login.
So based on your controller definition your route should be as following:
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Login}/{id?}");

I successfully reproduced your error as following:
Output:






I want to view the index.cshtml page. How do I design this page? What
should I create in Food and FoodService?

I am not sure which index.cshtml you would begin with when the application loads first time. As per your current coniguration it will load the login page first.
However, if you would like some other view to load first then you would define the route with that controller and action name.
Note: Please refer to this official document if you would like to learn more about how the route should define in asp.net core from .NET6 to current version.

first of all thank you for your answer. I made some changes in my code
It's currently heading to the index, but this time I'm having a problem.I updated the codes in the question. Can you look at it again? I would be very happy if you could help me.

What's the problem now?

resp returns null, this is the problem.

I think this is not related to this issue. Where you are getting null?

'resp.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

You haven't shared what 'resp.Result' is? Could you please share the full details.
